# Android: best way to make a View disappear after a defined amount of time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-animation, textview

I would like to make a textView disappear after a define amount of time succeeding a change of the text.

I am not sure what the best way to proceed is.

The problem of using `Thread.sleep(2000);`, is that it would obviously make the whole UI thread sleep. Using `Thread.sleep(2000);` inside an `AsyncTask` seems wrong. In addition, it would lead to problems if the user leave the Activity that needs to be updated by the `AsyncTask`.

There must be a cleaner way to implement that. If you know any: feel free to answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a handler:

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While trying your implementation, I noticed that the method is called postDelayed() .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Runnable` for this:

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Hide your view
    }
};
```

Then after your change of text, add the following:

```
myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this?

In your activity, create a handler:

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
{
  @Override
  public void handleMessage (Message msg)
  {
    if (msg.what == HIDE_VIEW)
      hideView();  // defined elsewhere in your activitry
  }
}
```

And at the point where you want to start the timer, do this:

```
postDelayed (new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = HIDE_VIEW;
    msg.obj = null;
    handler.sendMessage (msg);
  }
}, 10000);
```

Not sure if you need this level of asynchronousity.

Comment: This indeed a bit too complex for my particular problem, but it is definitely a useful answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the wrong interpretation of the question,

Use 
`textView .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

within a handler

Comment: He/she is trying to use a Thread because of the intention to make the view disappear only AFTER a certain amount of time has passed.