# Animate a loop of views indefinitely

Tags: android, loops, animation, tablelayout

[image]

I have created the attached animation using this:

```
public AnimationDrawable setAnyLine(AnimationDrawable animationDrawable) {

        animationDrawable.addFrame(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_01), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.animation_delay));
        animationDrawable.addFrame(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_02), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.animation_delay));
        animationDrawable.addFrame(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_03), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.animation_delay));
        animationDrawable.addFrame(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_04), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.animation_delay));
        return animationDrawable;
    }
```

What I want to do is populate a `TableLayout` with data from an `ArrayList` insted of using images.
I want to add a `View(TableLayout)`, let it sit for 750millis, then replace it with another `View` populated from another element of the array and let it there for the same 750millis until de end of the `ArrayList`, and then Restart the `Animation` again.

Can anybody give me a hint on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work and lots of readings [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243764/5482999) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165976/5482999) posts lead me to the result I was looking for.
Attached is the end result. Next would be to override transitions.

[image]

Comment: Please embed the answers in this post so that others aren't forced to follow links for the answer.